# What are the ways I can report questions that cover topics that potentially violate the CoC?

Tags: discussion, new-users, code-of-conduct

There was a [recent question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/363838/discussing-offensive-content-without-endorsing-it) by a new user asking about various posts that they found offensive, or may be in contravention.

In the topics some of our sites discuss, there may be material that some may consider offensive or against the Code of Conduct. An experienced user has the access and the knowledge to know when and how to flag such content, and how to use the local metas effectively. New users do not have such knowledge or access.

How can we recommend that new users deal with older, potentially inappropriate content in an appropriate manner? What would be the appropriate options for users of lower reputation levels and how do we communicate to them the community norms about such subjects?

Answer (score 15):

The [Code of Conduct itself](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/conduct)  tells you how to report:

[image]

You can flag the content if you have the reputation that's necessary to flag. Use the 'rude or abusive' flag for clear-cut violations, or a 'in need of moderator intervention' flag when you're not so sure or want to provide a bit more context as to what actually is offensive (things like [dog whistles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dog_whistle_(politics)) for example might be a good candidate for more context).

If you don't have an account or the necessary reputation, use the ['Contact Us'](https://meta.stackexchange.com/contact) option, and pick the option 'I want to report a Code of Conduct violation'. Use the text box to provide as much information as possible and don't forget to link the post.