# The styling for lists (numbered and bulleted) got switched to None

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, list

The answer [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/366232/) has a numbered list in it.

This is the markdown:

```
1. one
2. two
3. three
```

But in the post that gets boring:

1. one
2. two
3. three

Funny enough the HTML looks okay, but for CSS rules we only seem to get a default from [Stacks](https://stackoverflow.design/product/base/lists/):

[image: Inspecting the ol tag shows a CSS rule of list-style: none for both the ol and ul elements.]

and no additional CSS style is added to give that list its numbers back. Are you maybe missing a `list-ls-decimal` class on the `<ol>` element?

Do note that in the [Mobile view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2aAqf.png) the numbered list still works. So be careful if you have a regression somewhere.

Can you please count to 6 and 8 while you look where that CSS rule went missing? If you have   found it would you be kind enough to restore it in its former glory?

Comment: Can confirm: affects multiple users: me.

Comment: This isn't just a problem on meta.   I just wrote a post on [webmasters.se] and couldn't get list formatting to work in it.

Comment: In addition to the missing bullets and numbering, the indentation is also gone.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller yeah, I'm pretty confident it is broken across all sites. At least that means  only one fix is needed ....

Comment: Just tracked this one down. On it!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Ok, this is all fixed up. Thanks for posting it! This was related to some removal of "unused" CSS. Just a bit of housecleaning.

Here's the related issue over on [Stacks](https://github.com/StackExchange/Stacks/issues/688). Basically, we have some list resets that exist in Stack Overflow production, but this is definitely something we'd want to move to Stacks. Heck, I thought it was already there, and hence, the list styling getting busted today.

Y'all can take it out of my paycheck

Comment: Wait... you get a paycheck?? 

Comment: Not after this stunt I pulled today, @BenjaminHodgson

Comment: Just a tiny correction for your benefit: https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/47260

Comment: We're completely joking, @Levente. I don't get out of bed for less than $20k/day 

Comment: Sounds way better! ;)