# Is the "Segoe UI" font reverted on Windows OS?

Tags: support, bug, status-completed, design, fonts

Until yesterday I saw that the "Segoe UI" font was used on Meta Stack Exchange due to the recent font change: [We are switching to system fonts on May 10, 2021](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/364048/312043).
But now I can see "Arial" font applied everywhere on this site. The other Stack Exchange sites still have the "Segoe UI" font.

So, is the change intentional?

| Configuration | Version |
| --- | --- |
| Operating System | Windows 10 Pro |
| Mozilla Firefox | 89.0 (64-bit) |
| Google Chrome | 91.0.4472.77 (Official Build) (64-bit) |

Comment: Yup, the font being used now is `Arial, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif`, pretty sure same as it was before the change. On purpose or a bug, I can't really tell though.

Comment: This is not limited to Windows. As a MacOs user I saw font changes applied yesterday evening: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/364048/we-are-switching-to-system-fonts-on-may-10-2021?noredirect=1&lq=1#comment1220520_364048

Comment: @Luuklag yeah, maybe someone important enough posted a tweet that they don't like the font change.

Comment: And now, the font became visibly smaller, in particular the “modified XX minutes ago” notices (I’m not on Windows).

Comment: @ShadowTheVaccinatedWizard Seems some more issues, [New onboarding for review queues](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/363485/312043) is not working, reference: Learn more link in the [close votes review page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/review/close) redirect to page, instead of open as a popup.

Comment: It's weird to me that we've had a quick string of ~4 or more (This one, [#2](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/366329/profile-images-are-pushed-to-next-line-if-tags-extend-too-far-to-the-right), [#3](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/366321/ignored-and-watched-tags-seem-broken), [#4](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/366240/the-styling-for-lists-numbered-and-bulleted-got-switched-to-none)) styling bugs in the last couple days, that's not really normal.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Fixed! We deployed a canary build to some servers that was pointing to a branch that didn't have the font changes (and many more) merged in yet.

Comment: @Catija: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/361478/make-display-of-reputation-in-revisions-list-consistent-with-the-user-card-displ

Comment: @Luuklag That bug doesn't look like it relates to review pages - but maybe you meant revision. Either way, it's not showing the full number right now.

Comment: Then I'm lost @Catija. Anyways that posts deserves some sort of status, at the minimum it can't be reproduced.