# Lists using #) instead of #. break on render, but not preview, for this old post

Tags: bug, design, markdown-preview, list

[This question](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/74350/) looks like this in the editing preview:

[image: preview with working lists]

Here the #) list formatting works. But when the question renders on-site, it looks like:

[image: render with non-working lists]

The #) list has lost its formatting and shows up as plain text. I believe the style of #) is supposed to work for numbered lists, or at least I recall seeing it before. Why does this happen?

(The other kind of numbered list formatting - #. - [still works](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/366232/))

##### Examples on a fresh post:

###### Ordered list using `#.`

1. List item 1 with `1.`
2. List item 2 with `2.`
3. List item 3 with `3.`

###### Ordered list using `#)`

Does display as a list in preview.

1. List item 1 with `1)`
2. List item 2 with `2)`
3. List item 3 with `3)`

Comment: I don't see anything in the help pages indicating that the `#)` format should work. OTOH, it [is part of Commonmark](https://spec.commonmark.org/0.30/#list-items), so I would expect it to work, given that SE is supposed to be using modified Commonmark at this point.

Comment: @Makyen yeah, I couldn't find it documented anywhere either. However I remember it working before, and it works in the preview, so *\*shrug\** bug report.

Comment: The examples edited into the question works... huh?? (I was going to protest that examples weren't needed in the question itself, but now this is intriguing)

Comment: Ohhh... I didn't go to the question you linked. It was last edited when it was posted in 2018, so it's never been re-rendered using the Commonmark Markdown converter. So, just save an edit.

Comment: @Makyen that fixed it. Feeling a little silly now :) Any opinion on what to do with the meta question now?

Comment: If you don't want to delete it, I'd rewrite it to more accurately reflect the issue: old post not rendered under Commonmark, makes it look like there's some problem with formatting, with the additional strangeness that it's OK in the preview. Then you can just self-answer that it can be fixed by re-rendering, which is triggered when a new revision is saved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem is caused by the `#)` style not working before the [Commonmark migration](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/348746/). Since this particular post hadn't been edited since the migration, it hadn't been rendered with the new formatting. Editing to force a re-render [fixed the problem](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/74350/69582). The preview works because it's Commonmark compliant.

Comment: There's a number of posts where this is the case, including posts using code fences before they were supported. Manual cache kicking is necessary, unfortunately